# Requesting Run time permission in android in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add runtime permission feature in my react native app but unable to add. Please help me. Here is my code. I have tried all the methods but it is not working.

```
samplefunction=()=>{

  async function requestCameraPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        {
          'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
          'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                     'so you can take awesome pictures.'
        }

      )
      if (granted === true || granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){

        console.log("You can use the camera")

        Alert.alert("You can use the camera")

      } else {

        console.log("Camera permission denied")

        Alert.alert("Camera permission denied")

      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }

  requestCameraPermission(false);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have added this line in AndroidManifest.xml before you use thePermissionAndroid feature:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: Can you please explain why I need to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml, asking these permissions at runtime should work fine? I have a working project where I am asking storage permission at runtime and without adding them in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @RajatGupta According Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#perms) about Permissions, you need add premissions in manifest file if your app need. But this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) says that starting in API level 19, permission is not required to read/write files in **your application-specific directories** returned by two specific functions. So I guess your app is actually using these functions to write an app-owned space on the device and ask permission doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

The permission mechanism is asynchronous, and returns a promise. You should `await` the result:

```
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request( ...
```

Comment: I have try that but its still not showing the run time permission dialog.

Comment: Is your api version high enough?

Comment: Yes It's android marshmallow. Can you please post the sample code .

Comment: I see you've taken your code from the example in the docs. It should work, as long as your project was created correctly (see [the top of the page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html))

Comment: I have created the project correctly but its showing error.